# Django | OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available, disappears on page reload, whats wrong?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am sometimes getting the following error in Django, which disappears on page reload, I don't know how to reproduce it. I tried to set wait_timeout to 12 hours in *my.cnf*, but the error appeared again on `mysqld restart`, though did not when I restarted mysqld again, very wierd for me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".../python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 131, in _cursor
return self.create_cursor()
File ".../python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 536, in    create_cursor
cursor = self.connection.cursor()
File ".../python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1231, in cursor
raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use django 1.6? Maybe there are no requests for particular process for 12 hours? Seems like connection was broken by timeout and reopen in next request. Try to set  CONN_MAX_AGE=3600 in database section of django settings file. If this value less than wait_timeout in mysql config you prevent connection timeout error.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#conn-max-age